# .htaccess mod_rewrite is messing up brackets [ ] in my URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed a few things in my .htaccess file a few days ago and just now noticed that brackets in the URL are now messed up. Instead of:

`url.com/admin/page?delete[]=12345&reasons[]=2`

the URL shows as:

`url.com/admin/page?delete%255B%255D=12345&reasons%255B%255D=2`

What could be causing this? Here's my `.htaccess` file. It's driving me crazy!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^admin/page/?$ admin/page.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/profile?user=%1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product?name=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/profile?user=%1 [L,QSA,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product?name=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^admin/page/?$ admin/page.php [L,NC]
```

- Keep redirect rules before rewrites and use `NE` flag in each redirect rule.
- Make sure to clear browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tested it and it works perfectly. You really saved me! :)